# placing class defined tkinter object on an individual frame when many are defined using tk.Tk

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, toplevel

Following a suggestion that I got from Sentdex I have coded a multiple page Python/Tkinter application which among other things provides a time-moving graph on a single frame of a suite of many frames that live under tk.Tk. The coding of a moving graph was slightly complicated so I chose to define the canvas in a class: GrpCanvas(tk.Canvas).

My problem is that this program structure seems to cause the canvas object to appear on all 21 of my page-frames! How can I manage the code so that the `graphcanvas=GrpCanvas(HomePage)` only appears on that page? I have commented out some parent definitions to show what I have tried to do (and failed). I am using Python 3.4.4.

I show the code (cut down as much as I can to show the problem) below:

```
#Avoiding canvas on all pages when pages are managed using tk.Tk

import tkinter as tk

sinewave_points=[]  #Generated by a sin function of time.
#class GrpCanvas(self, parent):
class GrpCanvas(tk.Canvas):    
    #def __init__(self, parent):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):    
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, height=340, width=594, bg='white')#,      x=pos_x, y=pos_y):
        self.place(x=180, y=80)

    def set_y_scale(self, sinewave_points):
        self.scale=100 #actually calculated from a scaling algorithm (adapting to amplitude of sinewave_points)
        return self.scale

    def define_graph(self, scale, sinewave_points):
        # create x-axis
        self.horizontal=self.create_line(0, 170, 594, 170, width=2) 
        for i in range(13): #used to be 26
            x = 20 + (i * 48)
            self.x_scale=self.create_text(x, 175, font=("", 6),\
                                      anchor='n', text='{}'.format(((12/3) * i)-24))

        # y-axis
        self.vertical=self.create_line(20, 330, 20, 10, width=2)
        self.y_scale=self.set_y_scale(sinewave_points)

        if self.y_scale == 100:
            for i in range(21):
                self.y = int(330 - (i * (320/20))) #In fact there is an slgorithm to scale the y-axis
                #print(i, self.y)
                self.y_axis=self.create_text(17, (self.y), font=("", 6), anchor='e',\
                                text='{}'.format(int((((200/320)*(320/20)) * i)-\
                                100)))


        for i in range(len(sinewave_points)):                    
            self.x, self.y = (i+20) , int(-1*self.scale*sinewave_points[i])+ 170
            self.history=self.create_oval(self.x - 1, self.y - 1, self.x + 1,\
                                      self.y + 1, width=0, fill='purple')



class Moving_Sinewave(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        #Initialising Tkinter    

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, 'Sinewave Moving Plotter')
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, '800x480')#This is the size of the screen (in pixels)       

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill='both', expand= True)#(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure (0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (HomePage,                 
              SystemConfigPage,                   
              ConfigAlarmsPage):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            frame.configure(background= 'ivory2'),
        self.show_frame(HomePage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):       
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class HomePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller=controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global time1, time2, time4, time5

        sysconfigbutton=tk.Button(self, text= 'System\nConfiguration',        
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemConfigPage),
                              height=2, width=12)
        sysconfigbutton.place(x=20, y=80)

        #graphcanvas=GrpCanvas(tk.Frame)            #works with:    class GrpCanvas(tk.Canvas):    
                                                            #def __init__(self, parent):
        #graphcanvas=GrpCanvas(HomePage)            #works with:    class GrpCanvas(tk.Canvas):    
                                                            #def    __init__(self, parent):
        #graphcanvas=GrpCanvas(HomePage(tk.Frame))

        graphcanvas=GrpCanvas(HomePage, controller.tk)# works with: class GrpCanvas(tk.Canvas):    
                                                    #def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        graphcanvas.define_graph(graphcanvas.set_y_scale(sinewave_points), sinewave_points)
    # This actually plots the points

class SystemConfigPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        configalarmsbutton=tk.Button(self, text= 'Configure\nAlarms',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ConfigAlarmsPage),                                 
                            height=2, width=12)
        configalarmsbutton.place(x=20, y=180)

class ConfigAlarmsPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        backbutton=tk.Button(self, text= 'Back',
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage),
                               height=2, width=12)
        backbutton.place(x=20, y=380)


app = Moving_Sinewave()             
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `GrpCanvas` needs to be the parent widget in which the canvas is to appear. In this specific case you should use `self`, since you want it to be in the home page and you are creating it as part of creating `HomePage`:

```
graphcanvas=GrpCanvas(self, controller.tk)
```

You also need to pass this argument on to the `__init__` of the parent class, which you are neglecting to do. To fix that, change this:

```
tk.Canvas.__init__(self, height=340, ...)
```

... to this:

```
tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent, height=340, ...)
```

What was happening is that because you didn't pass in the parent, the widget was using the root window as the default. And because you were using `place`, and because this widget was getting created last (and thus was at the top of the stacking order) it was appearing on top of all of the pages.

Comment: Thank-you that works perfectly. I could not have seen this.